# Centralizar campos de login e senha

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-3

Então, eu estou fazendo um sistema de login com Bootstrap (aprendendo) e acabei que não consigo deixar os campos Login e Senha centralizados, consegui antes mas inserindo um left: 40%, porém acaba ficando desproporcional, como eu poderia arrumar isso?

Segue código e imagens de como está:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="menuLogin">
        <div>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imagens/Logo" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group" style="position: relative;text-align: center; ">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" type="password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; width: 150px"> 
            ENTRAR
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também gostaria de saber como eu poderia aumentar a largura do botão...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umas das fomas de centralizá-lo é utilizando o `text-center` no `<body>` exatamente como no [exemplo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/) do próprio site do bootstrap:

```
 <body class="text-center">
   <form class="form-signin">
   </form>
 </body>
```

A largura do botão pode ser definida através da adição das classes `btn-sm` para o botão ficar menor, `btn-lg` para ficar maior e `btn-block` para ocupar toda a lateral. Sugiro da uma lida na documentação: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/

Comment: Não funcionou, além da não ter a class form-signin, acho que só faz parte do 4.3, eu tenho que usar somente 3.3

Comment: @Dreidel faça o seguinte então, defina uma largura para o form e deixe o margin como auto: `<form id="form1" runat="server" style="width: 300px; margin: auto">`

Comment: @Dreidel a classe `form-signin` é do exemplo, não faz parte do bootstrap

Comment: Agora deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)
E desculpa a lerdeza haha..

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso aqui:

```
<div class="text-center">
```

**OU**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Os dois funcionam, verifique qual fica melhor no seu caso.

Comment: Em qual das divs eu uso essas classes?